# Simple native JS Calc

Tags: beginner, html, css, calculator, ecmascript-6

I've never been into web a lot, but I really want to. 
I started from simple things. I have some experience in **.NET** and **c#**. 
But the world of **javascript** is completely new for me. 
I wrote simple calculator just to try js.

Maybe there are some *ridiculous* things in my code that I want to know. 
I'm not really interested in functionallity of my project.

The main thing that I want to know are mistakes that could be dangerous in my future projects. So I will appreciate any advices.

P.S. Am I using **let** correctly? I read about that in [airbnb js guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript). And what about **onsumbit** event on Form? What is the best practice?

```js
window.onload = (function () {

    document.getElementById("user_input").value = "";

    let btns = document.getElementsByTagName("Button");
    
    for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
        if (!isOperation(btns[i].textContent)) {
            btns[i].onclick = function (e) {
                let userInput = document.getElementById("user_input");
                if (userInput === null) {
                    console.error("Error, user_input element is not found!");
                } else {
                    userInput.value = userInput.value + e.target.textContent;
                }
                return false;
            };
        } else {
            btns[i].onclick = function (e) {
                let part = document.getElementById("part");
                if (part === null) {
                    console.error("Error, part element is not found!");
                } else {
                    part.textContent = document.getElementById("user_input").value
                        + e.target.textContent;
                    document.getElementById("user_input").value = "";
                }
                return false;
            };
        }
        if (btns[i].textContent.toLowerCase() === 'c') {
            btns[i].onclick = function (e) {
                let user_input = document.getElementById("user_input").value;
                if (user_input.value !== null) {
                    if (user_input.length >= 1) {
                        document.getElementById("user_input").value =
                            user_input.substring(0, user_input.length - 1);
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById("user_input").value = null;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            };
        }
        if (btns[i].textContent === '.') {
            btns[i].onclick = function (e) {
                alert("I'm not working...");
                return false;
            };
        }
    }
});


function calc() {
    let part = document.getElementById("part").textContent;
    let userInput = document.getElementById("user_input");
    let operation = part[part.length - 1];

    document.getElementById("part").textContent = operate(operation, part, userInput.value);
    userInput.value = null;
}

function isOperation(a) {
    let operations = ['+', '-', '/', '*'];
    for (let i = 0; i < operations.length; i++) {
        if (a === operations[i]) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function operate(operator, value1, value2) {

    let num1 = parseInt(value1);
    let num2 = parseInt(value2);

    if (operator === '+') {
        return num1 + num2;
    } else if (operator === '-') {
        return num1 - num2;
    } else if (operator === '*') {
        return num1 * num2;
    } else {
        return num1 / num2;
    }
}
```

```css
 body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
h1 {
    text-align : center;
}
.calc {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}
table{
    margin-left: 82px;
    text-align:center;
}
button{
    width: 30px;
    font-size: 24px;
}
.buttons{
    text-align:center;
}w
#part{
    text-align:right;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>JS Calc Native</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="calc">
        <h2>Simple Native JS Calc</h2>
        <form onsubmit="calc(); return false;" >
            <p id="part"></p>
            <input type="text" id="user_input"/>
            <div class="buttons">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><button>7</button></td>
                        <td><button>8</button></td>
                        <td><button>9</button></td>
                        <td><button>+</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><button>4</button></td>
                        <td><button>5</button></td>
                        <td><button>6</button></td>
                        <td><button>-</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><button>1</button></td>
                        <td><button>2</button></td>
                        <td><button>3</button></td>
                        <td><button>/</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><button>C</button></td>
                        <td><button>0</button></td>
                        <td><button>.</button></td>
                        <td><button>*</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <input type="submit"  value="calculate"/>
        </form>
    </div>
<script src="calc.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The '.' gives an "I'm not working..." popup, and the '-' uses the wrong sign (6 -3 = -3?  3 - 6 = 3?).

Comment: @Hosch250 you right, wrong argument order in _operate()_ , thanks.